# Limit concurrently sql queries for one user

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a strange problem:

Basically I developed a PHP Form that when is submitted by an user the form will proccess an INSERT query with multiple values:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name
        (id, colB, colC)
 VALUES (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?) [,...]
```

So far there is no problem. The problem is that for a couple of reason (not relevant) I have to insert manually the ID of the rows that I'm going to insert so before this query I'm going to make also this query:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM tbl_name WHERE id < x
```

So I can take the id where to start my query.

Specifying that the queries will take more than a normal query because they're queries in an external database, it takes about 2-3s for the INSERT query.

The problem is:

If one user is going to submit the form, he take the reference ID, for example `45` and then the INSERT queries are processed:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name
        (id, colB, colC)
 VALUES (45, 2, 2), (46, 5, 7), (47, 1, 4) [,...]
```

But during the INSERT query another user submit the form and he take as reference ID one of the ID of the rows which is processing the other user.

How can I avoid this problem? I thought about limit concurrently sql queries for one user that I will use just for the website, but I don't have any idea how to do it. There's other solutions? Or maybe MySQL it already has a prevention to this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a unique id for a user, and can you alter the table schema?

Comment: Use transaction, then the next user would not do anything until the current user is finishing.

Comment: Yes I have an unique id and I can alter it. This is a table about the items of an user, and since I'm processing it from a website I have to separate the rows IDs from the other rows IDs that are already inside.

Comment: This is a very common scenario in multi-user applications and the solution is locking the records. There are various locking methods (optimistic, pessimistic,...). Also, you can put your update statements inside a transaction block, which automatically applies the lock.

Comment: This is a symptom of incorrect design. You're trying to limit your database's concurrency handling mechanism, and that's not the solution - that's a hack, at best. It's very important why you need to do `id` calculation the way you are doing it. There's 100% a different way to achieve what you're after, *without* this manual `id` calculation. That's the **core** of your problem. If you still insist on going about your way, what you need to do is place a `unique` constraint to this manually-calculated `id` value, if you haven't already. If two users get the same numbers, one user will error out

Comment: Autoincrement and last_insert_id takes care of all this. Sure, wheels need reinventing, but not on 150 rep.

Comment: Perhaps you should just [auto increment](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp) that id field? Then you don't even have to calculate/use that id in the insert statement.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL supports having rows **auto increment**, which would avoid your problem entirely. Using this would have 2 advantages: that you wouldn't need to worry about concurrent users - the db will just auto add the next id, and also you wouldn't have to hit the db twice - once to select the id and once to insert.
[This MySQL link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html) shows how to set the column to auto increment.